# Series divergent

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have a problem with proof of the divergence of this series:

$$\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt n }{\sqrt[3]n}$$

I got:
$$\ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]n(\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n)} \to 0$$

However, how can I prove that it is divergent? I suppose I have to use the comparison test.

Comment: You can prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\sim \frac{1}{2n^{5/6}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{n^{1/3}(\sqrt{n+1}+√n)}\gt$

$\dfrac{1}{n^{1/3}2\sqrt{n+1}}\gt$

$\dfrac{1}{2n^{1/3}\sqrt{n+n}}=$

$\dfrac{1}{2√2n^{1/3}n^{1/2}}=$

$\dfrac{1}{2√2 n^{5/6}} $;

$\sum \dfrac{1}{n^p}$ diverges for $p \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{\sqrt[3]n}}{\frac1{n^{5/6}}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{5/6}}{\sqrt[3]n\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)}\\&=\frac12,\end{align}and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{5/6}}$ diverges, your series diverges.

Comment: Could you write more detailed calculus? I have problem with the denominator.

Comment: You have changes your question and so I have change my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Why did you decide to use $\ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{4}{3}}}$?

Comment: Actually, it was an error; I should have written $n^{5/6}$. Anyway, it's because $\frac56=\frac13+\frac12$ and because $\sqrt[3]n\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\right)$ growths as $n^{1/3}\times2n^{1/2}$.

Comment: The method is: look at the growth of the denominator and comapare the series with the estimated growth ratio, using limit comparison test, isn't it?

Comment: I edited it to the correct exponent.